# How do you write an integral and why

Tags: integration, soft-question, notation

A. Year 1 Calculus Student Approach
$$
F(x) = \int f(x')  dx\, 
$$

B. Random math paper you find online approach 
$$
F(x) = \int dx f(x')  \,
$$

C. Spivak
$$
F(x) = \int f(x)  \,
$$

D. ???

(Edit) I'm asking because I read a post on Math Stackexchange that said something about dropping the dx is totally fine because it is not well defined. I'm curious as to what real mathematicians do.

Comment: $$\int f(x)\,dx.$$ There's no ambiguity about order of integration or what the variable being integrated is or anything of that sort. Most mathematicians will use this notation. Physicists tend to like the second notation for whatever reason (as a former physicist, I don't even understand the appeal).

Comment: I think Spivak actually writes $\int f$, not $\int f(x)$, but I may be wrong.

Comment: You can't drop $dx$ in general. Think of $\int xy.$ Then $\int xy dx$ is completely different from $\int xy dy$ or $\int xy dt.$ If you work with only a variable, say $x,$ and this is assumed you could drop $dx,$ although I am not sure if this is standard.

Comment: It's standard to drop the $d$_ if there's no ambiguity. This is because mathematicians can be lazy with respect to these things.

Comment: Does anyone ever use B? If so, are you trying to make explicit that the integral is an operator that operates on f?

Comment: B is pretty common for nested integrals in physics. You see it all the time in analytical mechanics of rigid bodies and optics, for one.

Comment: B is a **much** better style for nested integrals, so that you don't have to keep going from one end of the expression to the other to connect the variables with their intervals.

Comment: Also, $f^{(-1)}(x)$.

Comment: In some of my EE classes we use $D^{-1}$ rather than B, because the effect of the Laplace transform is to send D to s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer the following notation for integration 
\[ \int f(x)\ dx \]
I try to leave no room for ambiguity and to me this notation makes the integral clear, explicit and easily understood. Also the $dx$ can be read as "with respect to $x$".